# sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unterminated `s' command

Tags: sed

I tried to use the `sed` command to do some text replacement,

```
sed -i 's/port=\"8080\"/port="\8000\"' /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.37/conf/server.xml
```

But I meet this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unterminated `s' command
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Unterminated `s' command means you are missing a delimiter. You need 3 and have just 2 in your command.

```
sed -i 's/port=\"8080\"/port="\8000/"' /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.37/conf/server.xml
```

I flipped the last \ to / and it works:

```
more test
  port="8080"
sed -i 's/port="8080"/port="8000"/' test
more test
  port="8000"
```